# display .pdf files in swift on an iPad?

Tags: ios, pdf

I am a embedded developers (C++) and I try to learn swift. So I do not really know how to create such an apps  - but I need such an App :-) 
The basics of the language I understand, but:
How do I view a .pdf file in SWIFT?

I have a blank page on the iPad (in the View Controller). But then I do not know what to do next.

I want to show a list of .pdf files - that are on the the MacBook.
So first I have to somehow transmit / read / import a list of .pdf files (all in one folder of the MacBook)
Then I want to select one of these files and then I want to view that file in my Swift App (as a first step).
I think I know how I create and display a list.
But as I read this list (or better still, a directory that is on my MacBook as a list) then in the app on an iPad? And how can I save THIS list and access it to show this .pdf as a .pdf?

Can I build such an app without ObjC? Or I'll have to learn ObjC yet?

Comment: I would also be grateful for the help to only a single step

Comment: You can use UIWebview for Displaying PDF file.